# How to flatten a sequence within a case class

Tags: scala, scala-collections, flatten, flatmap

In Scala, is it possible to use flatmaps more efficiently with case classes containing arrays to be exploded?

Here is a code that works, but doesn't look right:

```scala
object stuff {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        case class Stuff(name: String, stuff: Seq[String])
        case class FlatStuff(name: String, stuff: String)

        val someStuff = Array(Stuff("a", Seq("1", "2", "3")), Stuff("b", Seq("4", "5")))

        val stuffs = someStuff.flatMap(item => {
            val flatten = new Array[FlatStuff](item.stuff.length)
            for (i <- 0 until item.stuff.length) {
                flatten(i) = FlatStuff(item.name, item.stuff(i))
            }
            flatten
        })

        stuffs.foreach(stuff => println(stuff))
    }
}
```

Comment: For the final line, instead of "stuffs.foreach(stuff => println(stuff))" you can just write "stuffs.foreach(println)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a simple **for comprehension** will be more readable:

```
val stuffs = for {
  Stuff(name, stuffArray) <- someStuff // for each name & struffArray in someStuff.
  stuff <- stuffArray // for each stuff in stuffArray.
} yield FlatStuff(name, stuff) // Return a new FlatSutff.
```

As @user6337 explain in the comments, the **for comprehension** is just sugar syntax for `map` & `flatMap`.
Thus, the above can be rewritten as:

```
someStuff.flatMap {
  case Stuff(name, stuffArray) =>
    stuffArray.map {
      stuff => FlatStuff(name, stuff)
    }
}
```

Comment: @RicardoPiccoli A for comprehension can be decomposed into flatMap and map. See example 2 here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html